# File size increases after reading png file from disk and saving it back

Tags: c#, image-processing, png

I'm currently working on a small program to read png files from disk, do some modifications and save it back. Everything is running smoothly except for one small problem, after I saved the file back to disk, its size always increases, for example, a 27.1MB file will become 33.3MB.

After some debugging I finally narrow it down to my reading and saving code. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(<path to file>);
//omitted
img.Save(<path to new file>, ImageFormat.Png);
```

I've verified no matter if I do or do not make any modification, simply reading and saving the image will cause it size to change. Furthermore, if I opened the saved file with Paint and save from there, the file will shrink back to original size.

How do I read and save the image without changing its size?

Comment: Does it also happen if you re-read the same PNG using your C# program? If it doesn't, it's likely related to the level of PNG compression (the code you're using does less compression, Paint compresses more).

Comment: If I re-read the same saved PNG then its size does not increase anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the Endoder.ColorDepth field? PNG also supports transparency and might be saving some information not needed by your image.

```
ImageCodecInfo pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(codec => codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid)).FirstOrDefault();
if (pngCodec != null)
{
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 24); //8, 16, 24, 32 (base on your format)
    image.Save(stream, pngCodec, parameters);
}
```

Additional info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.colordepth(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Indeed transparency was the cause. I've used the code in this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33ce8f9f-5d4a-4b03-a2dc-b8323be3ebc5/remove-alpha-channel-png-to-bmp-conversion?forum=csharpgeneral but replace "Red" with "Transparent" and my problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you @gzup for keeping us posted with the solution that works for you.

Comment: Isn't the case for me; the code I made was specifically for removing the alpha channel on png images. The same paste-on-white-background-and-resave-without-alpha-channel operation gave me a 117k png file in Gimp, and a 145k png file in c#.

Comment: The .PNG encoder in .NET does not support any EncoderParameters - or has that changed??

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the color depth and how many channels (w/o alpha) are used, saved PNG file size depends mainly on two factors:

- How the pre-processing on image lines (called filtering) is done.
- The compression level for the deflate algorithm (0-9).

This two factors will greatly affect the output image file size. Filtering is empirical and you can use one out of 4 filtering algorithm for all image lines or different algorithms for different lines or even adaptively try different algorithms on individual lines and choose the largest compression rate. The adaptively way is the most time consuming and impractical for most image writers.

After the filtering, image data is deflate compressed. The compression level for deflate algorithm usually ranges from 0-9 from lowerest to highest compression rate. The higher the compression rate, the slower the compression process. Usually 4 is the best for most of the images.

The filtering process plays a very important sometimes crucial role in PNG compression process. Different filtering algorithm may result in large difference in saved image size. On the other hand, image size is less sensitive to compression level.

You can use tools like TweakPNG to check about the color depth and number of channels the image contains. If the original and the re-saved image has the same color depth and channels, then most probably the filtering and compression level are the culprit for the increased file size.

The truth is if the encoder is not optimized, more often than not, the file size will increase. There are however a lot PNG optimization softwares out there if you don't mind post-processing your resulting images.

Comment: A third factor is whether the file was written with an inappropriate color type, such as writing a grayscale image as truecolor or writing an alpha channel even for opaque images, wasting filesize.  Many applications will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the **compression** part.
Add to your code like this -

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(<path to file>);
```

here is what you missed -

```
ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 25L);
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
```

and save like this -

```
img.Save(<path to file>, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
```

Here is the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80(v=vs.110).aspx) link. hope it helps.

Comment: This solution convert the image from png to jpeg, while I need the file in png format. If I change EncoderInfo to "image/png" then  setting compression does not thing, I still got a slightly bloated image.