# How to make Bitmap transparent and 24bpp?

Tags: c#, mono, png

This code creates 32 bit png instead of 24 bit png in Mono:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(bmpWidth, bmpHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
bmp.MakeTransparent();
ImageCodecInfo pngCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(codec => codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid)).FirstOrDefault();
if (pngCodec != null)
{
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 24);
    png.Save("mycopy.png", pngCodec, parameters);
}
```

[File size increases after reading png file from disk and saving it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396173)

I know this because of file size:

```
$ du -b *.png
506 original.png
611 mycopy.png
```

and pngcheck says

```
OK: mycopy.png (16x16, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 40.3%).
```

instead of

```
OK: original.png (16x16, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced, 34.1%).
```

This is because Mono's implementation of `MakeTransparent` creates 32bpp Bitmap internally to handle transparency.

Is it possible to create transparent 24bpp .png in mono with System.Drawing?

Comment: Does writing to "png24:mycopy.png" instead of "mycopy.png" work?  If not you could postprocess your file with ImageMagick's "convert mycopy.png png24:mycopy24bit.png".  Hopefully it'll still have transparency conveyed by a tRNS chunk.

Comment: Yes, <code>convert</code> command converts properly, no - png24 prefix doesn't work inside mono (gives "GDI+ Status: Generic Error" message). I want to know how to replace ImageCodec of mono with my own